# Visual Studio 2015 'use var' refactoring shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut for refactoring a line of code to use the `var` keyword similar to what ReSharper offers?

For example if you have the following piece of code:

```
public void Foo()
{
    List<Tuple<int, object>> bar = new List<Tuple<int, object>>();
}
```

ReSharper can format it into:

```
public void Foo()
{
    var bar = new List<Tuple<int, object>>();
}
```

Comment: None that I know of, but oh boy wouldn't that be nice!:)

Comment: I am sure there is a code analysis NuGet package out there by now that includes that. You just need to go find it.

Comment: If I were a coworker who might someday need to read your code, I would plead with you not to make a policy of this.  I suppose in this particular instance, the type of `bar` is obvious, but often the compiler can infer things that would require a developer to dig around in other code.

Comment: @adv12 That is a religious battle.  I'm firmly in the "use var whenever possible" camp.  So you and I clearly would not get along.

Comment: @adv12 how is it not clear what the type is - its right there on the same line. `var` just avoids repeating it unnecessarily!

Comment: @adv12 Yes agreed, i prefer to only use it in the cases where the type is obvious.

Comment: @Jamiec, yes, in this instance, as I said, it's right there on the same line.  I'm arguing against the general practice of removing type information, because often the type *isn't* right there on the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio does not have a direct equivalent to many of the ReSharper's refactoring tools. Unfortunately, "use `var`" is one of the missing refactoring features, at least as of VS 2015.

You can use this regex as poor man's refactoring. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, then type

```
Search:  (^\s*)\S[^=()]* (\w+\s*=)
Replace: $1var $2
```

The `"\S[^=()]* "` portion, including the space, matches the declaration, the `^\s*` matches indentation, and `\w+\s*=` matches variable name and `=` in front of initialization.

Indentation is captured into `$1` group; variable and `=` are captured into `$2`. Replacement string uses the two captured strings to format a replacement with `var` in the middle.

This trick can help you convert the entire file pretty quickly: visually confirm that you want to apply "refactoring" to the selected item, then press <kbd>→</kbd> button to go to the next declaration.

Although this approach lends itself to making a macro with relative ease, built-in support for macros has been dropped from Visual Studio as of VS 2010, so creating a quick shortcut manually for this type of refactoring would require installation of an external macro tool as well.

Comment: Well I still see this as a hack rather than "here's the the Visual Studio equivalent to ReSharper". Removed my downvote but this won't get an upvote.

Comment: @JimAho If there were a Visual Studio equivalent to ReSharper, it would be pretty hard for ReSharper to justify the big bucks they want you to pay them, no?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Saying that I think the author was clear that he/she was looking for _just_ a shortcut, like Resharper. Also Resharper remapped several of the CTRL+. commands, so the author's ask of equivalency isn't unreasonable.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My question was strictly related to finding (in this case) an *equivalent* to ReSharper. Some refactoring that ReSharper provides such as extracting a method does exist in Visual Studio as well. It sounds like you already know the answer to the question - and if you do - please update your answer and then i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: BTW this is broken for when it finds function parameters with default values, e.g. `   int parameter1 = 0, int parameter2 = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

While there is no direct way to do this now, support for this in Visual Studio [appears to be on the way](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7062) in a future release of Rosalyn.

In addition to @dasblinkenlight's answer, I would keep an eye out for any custom NuGet code analyzers that do this. If it shows up as a green-squiggly error, you can effectivly get your shortcut via a quick action: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

I haven't been able to find one yet (besides one that does [exactly the opposite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VarReplacer/) of what you're looking for).